# linux pygtail process coming back

Tags: python, linux, process, daemon

On centos have a process that runs python script which parses nginx logs using [pygtail](https://github.com/bgreenlee/pygtail)
After killing such process either with `ctrl+c` or `kill` command. Process halt to exist: ps aux | grep python doesnt show it. But after some time ~5 min, process is resurrected. Who is the necromancer which brings killed process back to life? and why? And how can I prevent this?

Comment: Have you checked your crontab file?

Comment: Also, it could be installed as a service.

Comment: Silly me, I forgot about crontab. I looked up provisioner script, and there was a line which creates crontab job to run each minute. Thanks @AleksAndreev for your help.